# Trouble with a javascript regex and replace

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to replace individual words in an input, and these words include international (Turkish) characters.  I am trying to do this as such:

`replace(/\s([\u0000-\u007F\u00c7-\u015f]+)\s/g, "<span>$1</span>");`

I have changed this around various ways in order to exclude spaces, this is just the most recent failed attempt.  What's happening now is, a paragraph is matched instead of the individual words.  In other tests, with slightly different incarnations of the above regex, half the word will be matched, with the boundary being at a special character (that is appropriately rendered elsewhere, strangely enough.)

Note that replacing `\s` above with `\b` doesn't help things.
What is a better way to accomplish what I'm trying to, in the above code?

Comment: Have you tried debugging this over at Regexr? http://www.regexr.com - Im not a lot of help but I found that debugging regex in JS is easiest there.

Comment: You may restrict the character class with a look-ahead like this: [`(?:(?!\s)[\u0000-\u007F\u00c7-\u015f])+`](https://regex101.com/r/cO7oZ9/1). But I guess all you need is [`[\u0000-\u001F\u0021-\u007F\u00c7-\u015f]+`](https://regex101.com/r/cO7oZ9/2) (exclude the space `\u0020` from the range). Do you really need to check word boundaries? Then you need to know which codes represent letters and digits.

Comment: If it's just the Turkish characters, you can use something like this : `/([\wçıöüğşÇİÖÜĞŞ]+)/g`. [Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y6cco25m/)

Comment: @somethinghere - Thanks for the link, that's helpful

Comment: @Seçkin - That works, thanks.  I actually tried something like that before and it didn't work.  Must have had something to do with the `\b` (word delineation). Put it as an answer?

Comment: @stribizhev - Looks like you're right, I don't have to check boundaries.  Thank you

Comment: @horsehair I've added a detailed answer, cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's just the Turkish characters, you can use something like `/([\wçıöüğşÇİÖÜĞŞ]+)/g`.

Here is a snippet:

```js
var original = document.getElementById('original');
var replaced = document.getElementById('replaced');

replaced.innerHTML = original.innerHTML.toString().
replace(/([\wçıöüğşÇİÖÜĞŞ]+)/g, "<span class='replaced'>[$1]</span>");
```

```css
.replaced {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<p id="original">
  These are some example turkish words: şeker, çay, yumuşak, bağ
</p>

<p id="replaced">
</p>
```

To break down the expression a little bit;

`[` opening square bracket to start specifying a character set
`\w` for detecting *words*.
`çıöüğşÇİÖÜĞŞ` for the special Turkish characters.
`]` closing square bracket to finish specifying a character set
`+` means *match one or more characters like this*.

---

Please note that this is a *hacky* solution, because it will simply match words **and** the special characters if there is any. It will only work for the character set you explicitly specify in your regular expression. [stribizhev's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33761679/824495) is more elegant.

> The space is `\u0020` and you can remove it from the code ranges ([see demo](https://regex101.com/r/cO7oZ9/2)).
>   `[\u0000-\u001F\u0021-\u007F\u00c7-\u015f]+`

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following approaches:

- The space is `\u0020` and you can remove it from the code ranges ([see demo](https://regex101.com/r/cO7oZ9/2)):

`[\u0000-\u001F\u0021-\u007F\u00c7-\u015f]+`

- You may restrict the character class with a look-ahead like this ([see demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/cO7oZ9/1)):

`(?:(?!\s)[\u0000-\u007F\u00c7-\u015f])+`

Note that the first option is much quicker and should be used, the second is just to show what regex can do in JS :)